# how use constants in .antmatchers.access()

Tags: spring, spring-security

I want to use some constants from `AuthoritiesConstants.java` in `.antmatchers.access():`

`.antMatchers("/first/**").access("hasAuthority('ROLE_ALL') and hasAuthority('ROLE_ME')")`

it works but I want use constant ALL:

`public static final String ALL = "ROLE_ALL";`

I tried:

`.antMatchers("/first/**").access("hasAuthority('AuthoritiesConstants.ALL')");`

but this doesn`t work.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work, because it is actually not referencing the constant. It assumes that `'AuthoritiesConstants.ALL'` is just a String literal and is evaluated as such.

```
.antMatchers("/first/**").access("hasAuthority('AuthoritiesConstants.ALL')");
```

You can try using something like:

```
.antMatchers("/first/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ALL);
```

Or if you need to reference the constants in access expression, you can use following syntax: `access("hasAuthority(T(com.example.AuthoritiesConstants).ALL) and ...")`, where `com.example.` is the package containing the `AuthoritiesConstants` class.

Comment: it`s work, but i want add condition in .access:.antMatchers("/first/**").access("hasAuthority('ROLE_ALL') and hasAuthority('ROLE_ME')"). How do it with "and"

Comment: yes, it`s work. Thank you very much. I tried to find answer before, but never saw using "T".